# Can I install a NPM Package in a Ionic Project?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

Its that simple...

How can I config and use a Node Module with Ionic? Its not a Ionic plugin... its a node package.. Every package on NPM has a descrption of how to configurate it using javascript. But when Im using the Framework Ionic I dont know where and how to configurate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an Ionic App is packaged through npm, and you can install dependencies to it as if it was a Node.js App itself, and dependencies installed will go to your package.json file as usual.

More information in the [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/using-npm/)